# Is it a problem when users have a spammy username?

Tags: discussion, spam, users

I noticed a new user named j658063 DOT mvrht DOT com, curious I went to the primary domain which leads to some sort of get rich quick site.  Perhaps they are hoping search engines will somehow parse the name into a link.  Maybe it is innocent and a convenient name.

However I am curious, is using such a name OK?

Comment: I guess your best bet would be to cast a moderator flag to have them investigate this user's legitimacy (spam bot, hacked account, ...). If this user has no posts, you can cast a flag on one of your own posts (or use the `contact us` button although it will probably be slower).

Comment: On the main meta site:  [Usernames as Advertising or Spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61249/usernames-as-advertising-or-spam) where the consensus seems to be to allow user names to be anything non-offensive.    I'm a bit dubious though because the example in that question is far less spammy than the one you point out here.

Comment: Also somewhat relevant [Is spam in the “about me” field a reason to worry?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105218/is-spam-in-the-about-me-field-a-reason-to-worry) about finding and disabling users that have created a spammy profile page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's okay. The name in-and-of isn't offensive and doesn't violate any site rules. Additionally the site itself (I didn't visit it, I am going by your description) isn't illegal in any way. It may not be very honest but I am sure anyone with half a brain will see right through it. (Because you have to have half a brain to run a website, right?)

Comment: *...half a brain to run a website...* sadly, with WP and others, this may be less and less true as each year passes. I am thinking we are down to about 1/3rd these days. [just kidding!] Actually, true web coders are being faced with more and more complicated and sophisticated technologies. Even though some are not too complicated, the layering, interoperability, and expectations are. Becoming as web coder is a serious hill to climb these days. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks John and closetnoc.  Yes I agree.  I started off as a PHP coder and now have a web hosting business.  I am glad I have the coding background as about 80% of my customer would be using WordPress, it helps me understand errors and fix minor bugs.  But W P is a really complex beast.